# Javascript micro optimisation for if statement

Tags: javascript, optimization, micro-optimization

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I have a question regarding how to optimise if statements.

I will show you two scenarios.

```
//first

var number = 10;
var calculationOneResult = functionOne(number);
var calculationTwoResult = functionTwo(number);

if (calculationOneResult === true) {
    //stuff
} else if (calculationTwoResult === true) {
    //more stuffs
}


//second

var number = 10;

if (functionOne(number) === true) {
    //stuff
} else if (functionTwo(number) === true) {
    //more stuffs
}
```

Here is my question:
In the first scenario, I am calculating two times.
In the second one, if the first function returns `true`, will it calculate the second `elseif` statement or will it skip it after doing the `stuff` ?

Comment: It will skip after doing the stuff

Comment: you need not to check against `true` in a condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code:

```
if(statement1) {
    // stuff
} else if(statement2) {
    // other stuff
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(statement1) {
    // stuff
} else {
    if(statement2) {
    // other stuff
   }
}
```

as there is no `elseif` in JavaScript - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Description).
So the answer is any function in `statement2` will be simply skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in an `else` clause executes if the `if` expression tests as `true`, so the second version of your code will definitely save a function call in such cases.